# Copy .sqlite file to the file system in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have a folder named assets which contains the .sqlite file. Now I want to copy it to the file system directory. I first declare it in pubsec.yaml file as an asset but I get the following exception. How should I do this?

> Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.

`Dart_NewStringFromUTF8` expects argument `str` to be valid `UTF-8`.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * Where: Script '/home/power/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
>   line: 320

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command '/home/power/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/doc/opening_asset_db.md

I figured that I was getting this error due to the huge size of my.sqlite database.

Comment: how did you add sqflite, i am facing problem adding dependency. 

  sqflite: ^0.2.2
  path: ../

this is my dependency.

Comment: @Itzdsp Try adding it the following way sqflite: any

Comment: I tried the same and it did not work. copied the same from gitter group it worked. Strange and funny! anyways thanks (Y)

Comment: @Itzdsp put it under dependencies with correct  formatting (i.e. space before line). I have faced problem before in other dependency. Also try with double quotes like this,  sqflite: "^0.8.3"

Comment: @Shreya will it copy the db every time the App is started?

Comment: No I don't think so

Comment: The link is broken, could you sum up the content or find a working link?